# Explain do while

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-while

I was doing some coding and I was confused with the output of this do while statement and could not understand how it works.

```js
let cupsOfSugarNeeded = 1;
let cupsAdded = 0;

do {
  cupsOfSugarNeeded = cupsOfSugarNeeded + cupsAdded;
  cupsAdded++;
} while (cupsAdded < 7);
// while (cupsAdded < 1); output 1
// while (cupsAdded < 2); output 2
// while (cupsAdded < 3); output 4
// while (cupsAdded < 4); output 7
// while (cupsAdded < 5); output 11
// while (cupsAdded < 6); output 16
// while (cupsAdded < 7); output 22

console.log(cupsOfSugarNeeded);
```

Comment: What, specifically, do you not understand? The final output of `22` or how a `do...while` loop works in general?

Comment: What would your expected output be?

Comment: "Do the code in between the curly braces `{}` while the condition `cupsAdded < 7` is true." The code in the Do block will always run before the while conditional is checked.

Comment: Could not understand the output, as you can see I have a few tests on it. The output was 1, 2 and it jumped to 4 and 7. Why not 3 as it was supposed to increment by 1.

Comment: `cupsAdded` is only being incremented one at a time? 1,2,3,4... not 1,2,4,7

Comment: Is it not by 1?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: that would be the definition of the `while (cupsAdded < 7) {...}` loop. It is important to note that in the case of a `do {...} while (...)` loop, the code between the curly braces will be executed once even if the condition is not true from the start.

Comment: @ZoliSzabó that's what the second sentence kinda says

Answer (score 3):

In comments you said:

> Could not understand the output, as you can see I have a few tests on it. The output was 1, 2 and it jumped to 4 and 7. Why not 3 as it was supposed to increment by 1.

`cupsAdded` is incrementing by 1, but it is `cupsOfSugarNeeded` which is output at the end, and that is *not* simply incremented by 1. There is some mathematical calculation of that variable for each of the 7 iteration of the loop

```
cupsOfSugarNeeded = cupsOfSugarNeeded + cupsAdded;
```

You can see what happens for each loop by adding 2 `console.log` statements (and perhaps a third just to have a gap between each iteration for readability)

```js
let cupsOfSugarNeeded = 1;
let cupsAdded = 0;

do {
  cupsOfSugarNeeded = cupsOfSugarNeeded + cupsAdded;
  cupsAdded++;
  console.log("cupsAdded",cupsAdded);
  console.log("cupsOfSugarNeeded",cupsOfSugarNeeded)
  console.log("")
} while (cupsAdded < 7);
```